# From String to NSDate in Swift

Tags: string, date, swift, format, nsdate

I've got a `string` containing a `date` in this format:
**Thu, 04 Sep 2014 10:50:12 +0000**

Do you know how can I convert it to:
**04-09-2014**
(*dd-MM-yyyy*)

of course, using **Swift**

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If the above doesn't work, this should do the trick:

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "US_en")
formatter.dateFormat = "E, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"
let date = formatter.date(from: "Thu, 04 Sep 2014 10:50:12 +0000")
```

Answer (score 8):

I know the answer to this question has already been accepted but the shown method in that answer doesn't exactly output the date in the format of *dd-MM-yyyy*. So I'm gonna post this anyway so someone might find it useful.

One of the cool features of Swift is extensions. So I'm gonna create this as an extention so that it's reusable.

Create a extension for `NSDate` and put this code in there.

```
import Foundation

extension NSDate {

    convenience init(dateString: String) {
        let dateStringFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        dateStringFormatter.dateFormat = "E, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"
        dateStringFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: "GMT")
        let date = dateStringFormatter.dateFromString(dateString)

        self.init(timeInterval:0, sinceDate:date!)
    }

    func getDatePart() -> String {
        let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"
        formatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: "GMT")

        return formatter.stringFromDate(self)
    }
}
```

And this is how you use it.

```
NSDate(dateString: "Thu, 04 Sep 2014 10:50:12 +0000").getDatePart()
```

Output: **04-09-2014**

You can change the formats in both functions to accept and output dates in various formats.

Comment: its working with         dateStringFormatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en") but when I try to run with another language it gives "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" How can I change language?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
let mydateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
mydateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEE, MMM d, YYYY hh:mm:ss.SSSSxxx"
let date = mydateFormatter.dateFromString(yourdatestring)
```

Check out for the current date format if its not working:
http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/datetime/

Answer (score 0):

From iOS 15, we can convert in this way:

```swift
let strategy = Date.ParseStrategy(format: "\(weekday: .abbreviated), \(day: .twoDigits) \(month: .abbreviated) \(year: .defaultDigits) \(hour: .twoDigits(clock: .twentyFourHour, hourCycle: .zeroBased)):\(minute: .twoDigits):\(second: .twoDigits) \(timeZone: .iso8601(.short))", timeZone: .current)
if let date = try? Date("Thu, 04 Sep 2014 10:50:12 +0000", strategy: strategy) {
    // 04-09-2014
    let dateString = "\(date.formatted(.dateTime.day(.twoDigits)))-\(date.formatted(.dateTime.month(.twoDigits)))-\(date.formatted(.dateTime.year()))"
}
```