# How to schedule a same local notification in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I just want to schedule a same local notification in Swift. For example I just want to schedule a message saying "It's time to calculate your bill for this month" and I want to send this same message again next month.

How to do this kind of local notification in Swift?

I have referenced followings but was not able to schedule a same message in next month ...

//http://thecodeninja.tumblr.com/post/89942124085/notifications-in-ios-8-part-1-using-swift-what-is
//[From String to NSDate in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25686284/from-string-to-nsdate-in-swift)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`UILocalNotification` has a `repeatInterval` property that lets you specify how often the notification should repeat. Note that this is an `NSCalendarUnit`, not just an arbitrary number, so you can only make a notification repeat once per calendar unit (second, minute, hour, day, week, month, etc.). See the [`NSCalendarUnit` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCalendar_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/NSCalendarUnit) for more options.

For example, you can make a notification repeat every month with:

```
notification.repeatInterval = .CalendarUnitMonth
```