# Schedule Local Notifications at Specific times in the day

Tags: ios, swift2, uilocalnotification

I want to setup a daily notification system for my app. It should notify the user twice a day, once at 8:00 AM (Hey there, your set of morning doses is ready. Wanna check it out?) and once at 7:00 PM (Ssup! Your evening Dose is waiting inside). I know that by doing this i'll run out of notifications in a month since there's a 64 notifications cap (for local notifications) but by then, the app will be live and i'll be done setting up remote notifications update.

I've looked at this question: [How to schedule a same local notification in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26214768/how-to-schedule-a-same-local-notification-in-swift) and the .Day is all good. I just need to know how to do it twice a day at those specified times;. Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:** how to set the specific time on the notification is part of the problem. The NSDate API is giving me funny time intervals (sinceNow/Since1973). I just want to set it to fire at 7 PM. :-/ Can't quite seem to do it with these NSDate apis unless I'm missing something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: .Badge, categories: nil)
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)

    let localNotification1 = UILocalNotification()
    localNotification1.alertBody = "Your alert message 111"
    localNotification1.timeZone = NSTimeZone.defaultTimeZone()
    localNotification1.fireDate = self.getEightAMDate()
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(localNotification1)

    let localNotification2 = UILocalNotification()
    localNotification2.alertBody = "Your alert message22"
    localNotification2.timeZone = NSTimeZone.defaultTimeZone()
    localNotification2.fireDate = self.getSevenPMDate()
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(localNotification2)
    return true
}

func getEightAMDate() -> NSDate? {
    let calendar: NSCalendar! = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)
    let now: NSDate! = NSDate()

    let date10h = calendar.dateBySettingHour(8, minute: 0, second: 0, ofDate: now, options: NSCalendarOptions.MatchFirst)!
    return date10h
}

func getSevenPMDate() -> NSDate? {
    let calendar: NSCalendar! = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)
    let now: NSDate! = NSDate()

    let date19h = calendar.dateBySettingHour(19, minute: 0, second: 0, ofDate: now, options: NSCalendarOptions.MatchFirst)!
    return date19h
}
```

Comment: hey! Thanks for the reply.... quick one... was hoping you'd tell me how to set the time to be 8: 00 AM / 7 PM because the NSDate API doesn't give me an option to set the time directly. only 'timeIntevalSinceNow/1970/reference' etc.  Or am i supposed to use one of those? If so how would i go about it? Thanks

Comment: Thanks bunch mate. I guess the calendar is what i didn't know about. Looked around and a few people had the same problem. Apparently the calendar API isn't updated in the documentation. But I'll have to confirm that. Anyway, You're a hero mate!

Comment: right quick before we call it done, I need to set the repeat interval to .Day for the notifications to recur on a daily basis, yeah?

Comment: It supposed be. You can set a fire time, and see if it will show the notification for the second time.

Answer (score 6):

**Update for Swift 4.2**

```
import UserNotifications
```

In AppDelegate confirm to `UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate` and in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

```
let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
            center.delegate = self;
            center.requestAuthorization(options: [UNAuthorizationOptions.alert, .badge, .sound]) { (granted, error) in
                if !granted {
                    print("Permission Declined");
                }
            }

let content = UNMutableNotificationContent();
            content.title = "HI";
            content.body = "Your notification is here";
            content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default;

            let gregorian = Calendar(identifier: Calendar.Identifier.gregorian);
            let now = Date();
            var components = gregorian.dateComponents(in: .autoupdatingCurrent, from: now)

            let hours = [8,19];

            for hour in hours {
                components.timeZone = TimeZone.current
                components.hour = hour;
                components.minute = 00;
                components.second = 00;

                let date = gregorian.date(from: components);
                let formatter = DateFormatter();
                formatter.dateFormat = "MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm";

                guard let dates = date else {
                    return;
                }
                var fireDate: String? 
                fireDate = formatter.string(from: dates);
                print("\(fireDate ?? "")"); // Just to Check

                let dailyTrigger = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour, .minute, .second], from: dates);
                let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger.init(dateMatching: dailyTrigger, repeats: true);

                let identifier = "Local Notification"
                let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: identifier, content: content, trigger: trigger)

                center.add(request) { (error) in
                    if let error = error {
                        print("Error \(error.localizedDescription)")
                    }
                }
            }
```