# SWIFT: Convert a date with the format E, dd, MMM, y, KK:mma

Tags: swift, nsdate

I am trying to convert a date from a String to NSDate with the following code:

```
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "E, dd MMM yyyy, KK:mma"
date = dateFormatter.dateFromString(strDate)
```

I have also tried the following formats:

1. EEE, dd MMM yyyy, hh:mma
2. EEE, dd MMM yyyy, KK:mm

but the out put is always nil

> Converted Tue, 12 Jan 2016, 7:30am to **nil** with the formatter E, dd MMM yyyy, KK:mma

I have also considered the follow StackOverflow posts:

1. [String to NSDate in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25686284/from-string-to-nsdate-in-swift)
2. [How can I convert string date to NSDate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24777496/how-can-i-convert-string-date-to-nsdate)

and I have been using [this link](http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/datetime/) as a reference for the date formats

Comment: Cannot reproduce, works on my machine.

Comment: What locale is set on your device? Are you aware that the code relies on the fact that the current locale language is set to English?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The typical reason is that your device is not set to English language. Note that parsing strings like `Tue` or `Jan` is language specific. That means you have to make sure the formatter has a correct language set, e.g.:

```
dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en")
```

Comment: Weird, my device is English... But I suppose being explicit would be good for devices not set to English.