# Convert string to date in Swift

Tags: swift, nsdate, nsdateformatter

How can I convert this string `"2016-04-14T10:44:00+0000"` into an `NSDate` and keep only the year, month, day, hour?

The `T` in the middle of it really throws off what I am used to when working with dates.

Comment: You want just Year , month , day , hour right ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [From String to NSDate in Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25686284/from-string-to-nsdate-in-swift)

Answer (score 397, accepted):

- Convert the ISO8601 string to date

  ```
    let isoDate = "2016-04-14T10:44:00+0000"

    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX") // set locale to reliable US_POSIX
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"
    let date = dateFormatter.date(from:isoDate)!
  ```
- Get the date components for year, month, day and hour from the date

  ```
    let calendar = Calendar.current
    let components = calendar.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day, .hour], from: date)
  ```
- Finally create a new `Date` object and strip minutes and seconds

  ```
    let finalDate = calendar.date(from:components)
  ```

---

Consider also the convenience formatter `ISO8601DateFormatter` introduced in iOS 10 / macOS 10.12:

```
let isoDate = "2016-04-14T10:44:00+0000"

let dateFormatter = ISO8601DateFormatter()
let date = dateFormatter.date(from:isoDate)!
```

Comment: the Z in "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ" solved what was not working for me

Comment: I just want year month and day, but this is not working for me

Comment: @Sneha If you don't want the hour just omit `.hour`

Comment: @vadian I did but I'm not getting

Comment: @Sneha What do you (not) get? Does the code crash? Then probably the `isoDate` string does not match the format. The second part is supposed to work in any case if you pass a valid date.

Comment: @vadian I want the date to be in dd-mm-yyyy but I'm getting as 2017-03-10 18:30:00 +0000 instead of 10-03-2017

Comment: `print` displays dates in UTC. The date object is midnight depending on your local time zone. If you want to get an zone independent date, set the time zone of the date formatter to `UTC`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137036/discussion-between-sneha-and-vadian).

Comment: @vadian This is an old answer but many questions link here. Could you please set the locale to `POSIX`? Otherwise parsing won't be correct.

Comment: @vadian how to convert `"2018-07-21T15:10:28.2329784 + 05:30"` in date? `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SS ZZZZ"` formate not working. i am block in stackoverflow to ask question may yout please tell me?

Comment: @AbecedarioPoint The whitespace character between the plus sign and the timezone is not compliant to the rules.

Comment: Please, please, use a parsing library for this. See my post below.

Comment: @thetrutz Is this real a reason for downvoting? Why should I use a huge third-party library for a standard IS8601 string which can be parsed in two lines of code?

Comment: All in one: ISO8601DateFormatter().date(from:"your string")!

Comment: @vadian, yes, ISO8601 is a collection of different formats. The above code will only parse one of them. Thus it will fail for all the others. E.g. if the server's date library is updated/changed or a locale is set, you will receive a different ISO8601 string and you program can not deal with it. If we agree on ISO8601 for a given value, then we should be prepared to fully handle it. That is what standards are for. And for the point "huge": 1k lines of code will not add much to your app compared to a single icon. But it will add reliability.

Comment: It took me few hours to realize that the trailing exclamation is needed or it will always be `nil` in `dateFormatter.date(from:isoDate)!`

Comment: List of all locales available here:
https://gist.github.com/jacobbubu/1836273

Comment: The POSIX locale must be set *before* assigning the date format.

Comment: @MartinR Darn, you caught me again. I just went thru all my related posts and fixed the order.

Answer (score 57):

Try the following Date Format.

```
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ssZZZ"
let date = dateFormatter.dateFromString(strDate)
```

For Swift 4.1:

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ssZZZ"
let date = dateFormatter.date(from: strDate)
```

Comment: Tried it, and date return nil after this.

Comment: Cannot convert value of type 'String' to type 'Date' in coercion

Comment: Anyone have return nil on date string check my answer

Answer (score 37):

In Swift 4.1 you can do:

```
func getDate() -> Date? {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"
    dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone.current
    dateFormatter.locale = Locale.current
    return dateFormatter.date(from: "2015-04-01T11:42:00") // replace Date String
}
```

Comment: How can I use that in label.text?

Comment: @ Emre Değirmenci , you can't use this in `label.text`, because it is in `Date` formate. You required String so convert this `Date` into `String` (OR) use like this `label.text = "\(getDate)" ` Try this.

Answer (score 30):

Swift 3.0 - 4.2

```
import Foundation

extension String {

    func toDate(withFormat format: String = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")-> Date?{

        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "Asia/Tehran")
        dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "fa-IR")
        dateFormatter.calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = format
        let date = dateFormatter.date(from: self)

        return date

    }
}

extension Date {

    func toString(withFormat format: String = "EEEE ، d MMMM yyyy") -> String {

        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "fa-IR")
        dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "Asia/Tehran")
        dateFormatter.calendar = Calendar(identifier: .persian)
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = format
        let str = dateFormatter.string(from: self)

        return str
    }
}
```

Answer (score 20):

make global function

```
func convertDateFormat(inputDate: String) -> String {

     let olDateFormatter = DateFormatter()
     olDateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"

     let oldDate = olDateFormatter.date(from: inputDate)

     let convertDateFormatter = DateFormatter()
     convertDateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMM dd yyyy h:mm a"

     return convertDateFormatter.string(from: oldDate!)
}
```

Called function and pass value in it

```
get_OutputStr = convertDateFormat(inputDate: "2019-03-30T05:30:00+0000")
```

and here is output

```
Feb 25 2020 4:51 PM
```

Comment: Do you think your input and output are the same?

Answer (score 18):

Converting string to Date in swift using the string extension
Swift - 5.0

```
    extension String {
         public enum DateFormatType {
        
        /// The ISO8601 formatted year "yyyy" i.e. 1997
        case isoYear
        
        /// The ISO8601 formatted year and month "yyyy-MM" i.e. 1997-07
        case isoYearMonth
        
        /// The ISO8601 formatted date "yyyy-MM-dd" i.e. 1997-07-16
        case isoDate
        
        /// The ISO8601 formatted date and time "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mmZ" i.e. 1997-07-16T19:20+01:00
        case isoDateTime
        
        /// The ISO8601 formatted date, time and sec "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ" i.e. 1997-07-16T19:20:30+01:00
        case isoDateTimeSec
        
        /// The ISO8601 formatted date, time and millisec "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ" i.e. 1997-07-16T19:20:30.45+01:00
        case isoDateTimeMilliSec
        
        /// The dotNet formatted date "/Date(%d%d)/" i.e. "/Date(1268123281843)/"
        case dotNet
        
        /// The RSS formatted date "EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss ZZZ" i.e. "Fri, 09 Sep 2011 15:26:08 +0200"
        case rss
        
        /// The Alternative RSS formatted date "d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss ZZZ" i.e. "09 Sep 2011 15:26:08 +0200"
        case altRSS
        
        /// The http header formatted date "EEE, dd MM yyyy HH:mm:ss ZZZ" i.e. "Tue, 15 Nov 1994 12:45:26 GMT"
        case httpHeader
        
        /// A generic standard format date i.e. "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy"
        case standard
        
        /// A custom date format string
        case custom(String)
        
        /// The local formatted date and time "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" i.e. 1997-07-16 19:20:00
        case localDateTimeSec
        
        /// The local formatted date  "yyyy-MM-dd" i.e. 1997-07-16
        case localDate
        
        /// The local formatted  time "hh:mm a" i.e. 07:20 am
        case localTimeWithNoon
        
        /// The local formatted date and time "yyyyMMddHHmmss" i.e. 19970716192000
        case localPhotoSave
        
        case birthDateFormatOne
        
        case birthDateFormatTwo
        
        ///
        case messageRTetriveFormat
        
        ///
        case emailTimePreview
        
        var stringFormat:String {
          switch self {
          //handle iso Time
          case .birthDateFormatOne: return "dd/MM/YYYY"
          case .birthDateFormatTwo: return "dd-MM-YYYY"
          case .isoYear: return "yyyy"
          case .isoYearMonth: return "yyyy-MM"
          case .isoDate: return "yyyy-MM-dd"
          case .isoDateTime: return "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mmZ"
          case .isoDateTimeSec: return "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"
          case .isoDateTimeMilliSec: return "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
          case .dotNet: return "/Date(%d%f)/"
          case .rss: return "EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss ZZZ"
          case .altRSS: return "d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss ZZZ"
          case .httpHeader: return "EEE, dd MM yyyy HH:mm:ss ZZZ"
          case .standard: return "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy"
          case .custom(let customFormat): return customFormat
            
          //handle local Time
          case .localDateTimeSec: return "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
          case .localTimeWithNoon: return "hh:mm a"
          case .localDate: return "yyyy-MM-dd"
          case .localPhotoSave: return "yyyyMMddHHmmss"
          case .messageRTetriveFormat: return "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ"
          case .emailTimePreview: return "dd MMM yyyy, h:mm a"
          }
        }  
 }
        
 func toDate(_ format: DateFormatType = .isoDate) -> Date?{
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = format.stringFormat
        let date = dateFormatter.date(from: self)
        return date 
  }
 }
```

we use like

```
    string.toDate(.isoDate)
    "1997-05-24".toDate(.isoDate)
```

Answer (score 17):

Swift 5. To see IF A DATE HAS PASSED:

```
let expiryDate = "2020-01-10" // Jan 10 2020

let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"

if Date() < dateFormatter.date(from: expiryDate) ?? Date() {
    print("Not Yet expiryDate")
} else {
    print("expiryDate has passed")
}
```

Answer (score 13):

Since iOS 15.0, we can convert a String to Date in a more swift way:

```
let strategy = Date.ParseStrategy(format: "\(year: .defaultDigits)-\(month: .twoDigits)-\(day: .twoDigits)T\(hour: .twoDigits(clock: .twentyFourHour, hourCycle: .zeroBased)):\(minute: .twoDigits):\(second: .twoDigits)\(timeZone: .iso8601(.short))", timeZone: .current)
let date = try? Date("2016-04-14T10:44:00+0000", strategy: strategy)
```

Answer (score 12):

Hi You have separate T Format and then convert as you like

```
// create dateFormatter with UTC time format
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"
dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: "UTC")
let date = dateFormatter.dateFromString("2015-04-01T11:42:00")

// change to a readable time format and change to local time zone
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEE, MMM d, yyyy - h:mm a"
dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone.localTimeZone() 
let timeStamp = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(date!)
```

Answer (score 6):

Just your passing your `dateformate` and your date then you get `Year,month,day,hour`. [Extra info](http://www.codingexplorer.com/swiftly-getting-human-readable-date-nsdateformatter/)

```
func GetOnlyDateMonthYearFromFullDate(currentDateFormate:NSString , conVertFormate:NSString , convertDate:NSString ) -> NSString
    {
        let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = currentDateFormate as String
        let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = Key_DATE_FORMATE as String
        let finalDate = formatter.dateFromString(convertDate as String)
        formatter.dateFormat = conVertFormate as String
        let dateString = formatter.stringFromDate(finalDate!)

        return dateString
    }
```

**Get Year**

```
let Year = self.GetOnlyDateMonthYearFromFullDate("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ", conVertFormate: "YYYY", convertDate: "2016-04-14T10:44:00+0000") as String
```

**Get Month**

```
let month = self.GetOnlyDateMonthYearFromFullDate("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ", conVertFormate: "MM", convertDate: "2016-04-14T10:44:00+0000") as String
```

**Get Day**

```
let day = self.GetOnlyDateMonthYearFromFullDate("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ", conVertFormate: "dd", convertDate: "2016-04-14T10:44:00+0000") as String
```

**Get Hour**

```
let hour  = self.GetOnlyDateMonthYearFromFullDate("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ", conVertFormate: "hh", convertDate: "2016-04-14T10:44:00+0000") as String
```

Answer (score 5):

I was getting crazy with this format as well.

See the solution below.

Your String that came from your back or another source:

```
    let isoDate = "2020-05-06 20:00:00-03"
```

Identify the date format

```
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd' 'HH:mm:ssZ"
    let date = dateFormatter.date(from:isoDate)!
```

Now that you have the date as Date() you can change to whatever format you want using the formatDate.string

```
    let formatDate = DateFormatter()
    formatDate.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"
    let drawDate = formatDate.string(from: date)
    print(drawDate)
```

Output:

```
    06/05/2020 20:00
```

Answer (score 4):

just 
Step 1 >
get the String value from JSON or dataSource

*Step 2 > create a local variable and assign it.*

```
let startDate = CurrentDashBoard.startdate
```

*Step 3> create an instance of DateFormatter.*

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
```

*step 4>
call the dateFormat from dateFormatter and provide saved date dataType.*

```
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss"("may be String formate")
```

*step 5>
Assign the Local variable to this variable to convert.*

```
let dateFromStringstartDate : NSDate = dateFormatter.date(from: startDate)! as NSDate
```

*Step 6>
provide your required date Formate by the following code.*

```
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"
```

*Step 6> Assign it to label/text*

```
cell.lblStartDate.text = String(format: "%@", strstartDate)
```

**Code:**

```
let startDate = CurrentDashBoard.startdate let dateFormatter = DateFormatter() 
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss" let dateFromStringstartDate : 
NSDate = dateFormatter.date(from: startDate)! as NSDate
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"
let strstartDate = dateFormatter.string(from: dateFromStringstartDate as Date)
```

Answer (score 4):

Swift 5.6

Here is an easy way to get a string and convert it back to string with Date in structure by String extension

Date String Example "2022-03-15T07:13:49.607+00:00"

If the date is not in the format "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSSZ"
It will return 01-01-70

```
import Foundation

extension String {

  func convertToDate() -> String {
   
      let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
      dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSSZ"
      if let dt = dateFormatter.date(from: self) {
          dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM-dd-yy"
          let formatedStringDate = dateFormatter.string(from: dt)
              return formatedStringDate
      }
    
   
      return "01-01-70"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes, converting string to Date in swift can result to return  nil  so that you should  add "!" mark to format.date function!

```
let dateFormatterUK = DateFormatter()
dateFormatterUK.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"

let stringDate = "11-03-2018"
let date = dateFormatterUK.date(from: stringDate)!
```

Comment: The exclamation mark will crash your program if the dateFormatter does return nil. Only use ! when you know it won't be nil or when you want your program to crash if a nil is returned.

Comment: Since all strings are hardcoded in the given example , it won't return nil out of a sudden. So in the case of hard coded (and thus well known) strings, unsave unwrapping the optional is indeed totally legitimate. However, in general the exclamation mark should not be used on dynamic values that are not well known to succeed in any case.

Answer (score 2):

In swift4,

```
    var Msg_Date_ = "2019-03-30T05:30:00+0000"

    let dateFormatterGet = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatterGet.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"
    let dateFormatterPrint = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatterPrint.dateFormat = "MMM dd yyyy h:mm a"  //"MMM d, h:mm a" for  Sep 12, 2:11 PM
    let datee = dateFormatterGet.date(from: Msg_Date_)
    Msg_Date_ =  dateFormatterPrint.string(from: datee ?? Date())

    print(Msg_Date_)
```

//output :- Mar 30 2019 05:30 PM

Answer (score 1):

Just use SwifterSwift.

```
stringDate = "2020-04-26T08:56:17.987Z"
let date = Date(iso8601String: stringDate)
```

Comment: **dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXXXX"** for such case...

Answer (score 1):

What about SwiftDate ?. The best Date and Time parsing and manipulation library for Swift.

https://github.com/malcommac/SwiftDate#1-date-parsing

Install using Cocoa Pods:
https://github.com/malcommac/SwiftDate/blob/master/Documentation/0.Informations.md#installation

And then:

```
import SwiftDate

// All default datetime formats (15+) are recognized automatically
let _ = "2010-05-20 15:30:00".toDate()
// You can also provide your own format!
let _ = "2010-05-20 15:30".toDate("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm")
// All ISO8601 variants are supported too with timezone parsing!
let _ = "2017-09-17T11:59:29+02:00".toISODate()
// RSS, Extended, HTTP, SQL, .NET and all the major variants are supported!
let _ = "19 Nov 2015 22:20:40 +0100".toRSS(alt: true)
```

Comment: you have to do `if let date = "2017-09-17".toISODate()?.date {` because these API return `SwiftDate.DateInRegion?` pretty annoying

Answer (score 0):

Please use an ISO8601 parsing library for doing this. There are too many ways how the string could be encoded. Don't rely on a specific format and don't rely on the server sending always the same. The problems start with the 'Z' at the end and it will extend through all varieties of the standard. A parsing library will handle all cases and will always provide a safe conversion - whereas a fixed formatting string is likely to fail in the future.

You could use one of these libraries. They are also available on CococaPods:

https://github.com/boredzo/iso-8601-date-formatter/

https://github.com/malcommac/SwiftDate

Take a look at the implementations. They are both several hundred lines long - for good reason.

With regards to the question: You can pull out the date components from the date using NSDateComponents. The example on the website covers exactly your case.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nscalendar/1414841-components?language=objc

Please be aware, that converting your date will take into account the time zone. You might want to set the 'locale' of the NSCalendar explicitly.