# Swift: How to parse date & time string with timezone abbreviation?

Tags: swift, datetime, dateformatter

I receive a date & time string from a server with an information about a timezone formatted in an unusual way:

`2017-05-05T12:24:16.286462Z[UTC]`

I would like to use `DateFormatter` to parse it, but I cannot figure out what date format should I use.

I tried parsing it with `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ'['R']'"` or something quite similar but with no luck.

Here is my code:

```swift
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en-US")
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ'['R']'"
let date = dateFormatter.date(from: date)
```

What is the right date format for this string?

Comment: Have a look at this [updated answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36862041/4056108)

Comment: @chirag90 Thank you for your help, but I'm trying to achieve quite the opposite. I'm searching for the way to parse string into date, not to print date as a string.

Comment: updated my comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK guys, I figured it out.

The right format is

```swift
"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z['zzz']'"
```

`zzz` is for a timezone abbreviation, while `Z[` and `]` are treated as a plain text.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach with `ISO8601DateFormatter`. The `[UTC]` portion is stripped with Regular Expression

```
let dateString = "2017-05-05T12:24:16.286462Z[UTC]"

let formatter = ISO8601DateFormatter()
formatter.formatOptions = [.withInternetDateTime, .withFractionalSeconds]
let date = formatter.date(from: dateString.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\[^\\[+\\]", with: "", options: .regularExpression))
```

Comment: Have you tested it? Are you sure that the hanging "Z" character will not be a problem?

Comment: @MateuszChechliński Yes, I'm sure. But feel free to use the pattern `"Z\\[^\\[+\\]"`