# RelativeDateTimeFormatter says a date from 2 days ago is yesterday

Tags: swift

I noticed a particular day that refers to two days ago was localised as `Yesterday` by the formatter. Is there a config to set to make this be 2 days ago instead? Here's code to replicate the issue:

```
func getDateFromString(_ dateTimeString: String) -> Date {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSZ"
    return dateFormatter.date(from:dateTimeString)!
}

let targetDateStr = "2022-02-08T19:50:11.333017Z"
let nowStr = "2022-02-10T16:57:10.000017Z"

let targetDate = getDateFromString(targetDateStr)
let now = getDateFromString(nowStr)

let formatter = RelativeDateTimeFormatter()
formatter.dateTimeStyle = .named
formatter.unitsStyle = .short
let s = formatter.localizedString(for: targetDate, relativeTo: now) // "yesterday"
```

I noticed that the formatter produces "2 days ago" only after 48 hours have passed, is there a way to change this behaviour so that any hour on 2022-02-08 gets considered 2 days ago?

**Edit**

Problem solved: need to remove the hours/minutes/etc. info from the date then the formatter behaves as expected. Thanks [@Dev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3434042/dev)

```
func getDateFromString(_ dateTimeString: String) -> Date {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSZ"
    let date = dateFormatter.date(from:dateTimeString)!
    let calendar = Calendar.current
    let components = calendar.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day], from: date)
    return calendar.date(from: components)!
}
```

Comment: I haven't used swift, but does the .date function return a date object that has only the date or both date & time? I imagine it would work if you just compared dates (the yyyy-MM-dd component) and not dates & times.

Comment: @Dev I was just trying to figure out how to remove the hours/minutes/etc. info from the date to test this out!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36861732/convert-string-to-date-in-swift

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't used swift, but does the .date function return a date object that has only the date or both date & time? I imagine it would work if you just compared dates (the yyyy-MM-dd component) and not dates & times.

Link to thread on removing timestamp components
[Convert string to date in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36861732/convert-string-to-date-in-swift)