# Swift - iOS Unable to convert to required date format

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate, nsdateformatter, nstimezone

I am using date picker in my application. After selects particular date, It's not able to converting to required format.

Datepicker date:

> 2021-07-21 13:53:38 +0000

expected format

> 21 July 2021

I am trying with below code

```
static func formatStringToDate(date: String) -> String? {
        
        
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"//this your string date format
        dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: "UTC") as TimeZone?
        let datee = dateFormatter.date(from: "2021-07-21 13:53:38 +0000")


        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "d MMM yyyy"///this is what you want to convert format
        dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: "UTC") as TimeZone?
        let timeStamp = dateFormatter.string(from: datee!)

        return timeStamp ?? ""
     }
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: `"2021-07-21 13:53:38 +0000"` doesn't match the format `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ" ` . This is the correct format for the example you specified `"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ZZZZ"`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert string to date in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36861732/convert-string-to-date-in-swift)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found solution.
Here it is

```
let date = formatToDate(date: datePicker.date) 

    static func formatStringToDate(date: Date) -> String? {
                    
            let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
            dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd MMMM yyyy"
            let formattedDate = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
            return formattedDate // "21 July 2022"
        
        }
}
```

Comment: The format `MMMM d, yyyy` does not match your desired output (e.g. `21 July 2022`.)

Comment: I unknowingly posted that wrong format here in solution, I corrected it. I forgot to edit my answer which is worked for me after posted query. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Actually the correct way to write this to get you desired format should be:

```
let date = formatToDate(date: datePicker.date) 

static func formatStringToDate(date: Date) -> String? {
                
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd MMMM yyyy"
    let formattedDate = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
    return formattedDate // "21 July 2022"
    
}
```

Comment: @Anilkkumar iOS - ReactNative I believe this is the best answer for what you trying to accomplish. Please accept.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, But, I have already posted my solution before you post.

Comment: I understand, but your solution does not produce the answer you said you were seeking. Please clarify your question to reflect your answer, instead of mine. Thanks.

Comment: I understand you reply, But, What I said, I did not used your solution since already I have posted solution of mine before you posted. You have posted same my answer looks like. Anyway I have upvoted you answer too. Thank you

Comment: The main difference between mine and yours is:  dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd MMMM yyyy" This is how you get "27 July 2022" Thanks for the upvote atleast.

Comment: I unknowingly posted that wrong format here in solution, I corrected it. I forgot to edit my answer which is worked for me after posted query. Thank you

Comment: That makes sense for the back and forth now. Thanks for updating.