# Formatting a date from a string in swift

Tags: ios, swift, date

i have the following date coming from a server `2019-09-05T10:37:49.494Z` as a string and i need to parse this and convert it to a format like this `Fri September 13,2019 12:36 AM` and back to a string again:
i found multiple question links but none of them are working for me [Question One](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36861732/convert-string-to-date-in-swift)
[Question Two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25686284/from-string-to-nsdate-in-swift)

it tried doing this:

```
let dateFormatterGet = DateFormatter()
let dateFormatterPrint = DateFormatter()
var rawDate = "2019-09-05T10:37:49.494Z"

dateFormatterGet.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"
dateFormatterPrint.dateFormat = "E, d MMM yyyy HH:mm"
var formattedDate = "Error Formatting date"
if let date = dateFormatterGet.date(from: rawDate) {
    formattedDate = dateFormatterPrint.string(from: date)
    print("Formatted Date : \(formattedDate)")
}else {
     print("There was an error decoding the string")
}
```

this fails printing the error message, what am i doing wrong and how can i fix it?

Comment: Almost there. `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ` vs `"2019-09-05T10:37:49.494Z"`. You see that there are numbers after the seconds? But you didn't tell the DateFormatter (through the `dateFormat`) how to parse them. So it fails. See there http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns (Fractional Seconds?)

Comment: i thought that was the zone?

Comment: ".494", that's not a zone. Which zone should it be?

Comment: i dont know i am getting this date from backend thats why i got confused so how should i change the formatting?

Comment: In `rawDate`, the "Z" could be standing for "Zulu Time Zone"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you don't tell `dateFormatterGet` how to parse milliseconds. Modify the dateFormat to:

`dateFormatterGet.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"`

Answer (score 2):

You are almost there.

A small tip playing with (NS)DateFormatter put the dateFormat above/under the date string.

```
yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ
2019-09-05T10:37:49.494Z
```

Then, add "spaces" to align and separate them.

```
yyyy - MM - dd 'T' HH : mm : ss      Z
2019 - 09 - 05  T  10 : 37 : 49 . 494Z
                                ^ ^^^
```

I highlighted the missing ones. You need to tell the `(NS)DateFormatter` through the `dateFormat` how to interpret theses additional characters.

Let's check the [documentation](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns).

It's

> Fractional Second - truncates (like other time fields) to the count of letters. (example shows display using pattern SSSS for seconds value 12.34567)

So using `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ` should interpret them and fix your issue.

That's how you fix your issue. And it explained your error.
But since as pointed by [@Zombie](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57818442/1801544) it's using a ISO format, use if available the [`ISO8601DateFormatter`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/iso8601dateformatter) if possible (iOS10+)
If in future cases you don't have an ISO something format, you can use theses tips ;)

Answer (score 1):

The format you provided seems like an iso 8601 date for this reason I would suggest using the `ISO8601DateFormatter`

You can specify the options to match your string
here is an example

```
let dateString = "2019-09-05T10:37:49.494Z"

let formatter = ISO8601DateFormatter()

formatter.formatOptions = [
    .withDashSeparatorInDate,
    .withFullDate,
    .withFullTime,
    .withFractionalSeconds,
    .withColonSeparatorInTime
]

// "Sep 5, 2019 at 12:37 PM"
let date = formatter.date(from: dateString) ?? Date()

//"Thursday, September 5, 2019 at 12:37:49 PM"
let formattedDate = DateFormatter.localizedString(
    from: date,
    dateStyle: .full,
    timeStyle: .medium
)
```

Comment: The format options can be simplified: `formatter.formatOptions = [.withInternetDateTime, .withFractionalSeconds]`